# Is there a way for me to require dependency inside chrome dev tool console?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools

I am using `chrome dev tool console` to debug my web application. I can write some javascript code on the console but I can't write something like `const _ = require('lodash')`. I wonder whether how I can make `require` work on console.

Comment: It depends on the module loader you use in the browser, you'd have to find a way to get a reference to the `require` method that gets passed to the modules when they are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, importing the libraries through script CDN source is the most common way.

Example:

```
async function loadScript(url) {
  let response = await fetch(url);
  let script = await response.text();
  eval(script);
}

let scriptUrl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js'
loadScript(scriptUrl);
```

Paste the above into your Chrome console, then try using lodash commands.

Example:

```
>  _.debounce
< ƒ Vt(n,t,e){function r(){c&&ve(c),i=c=p=v,(g||h!==t)&&…
```

Comment: How about the library is loaded via `npm install`? Can I load them locally?

Comment: Well the only way I really see them being accessible in the chrome dev tools environment is if you have the modules set as global variables in your project.

Comment: Right, setting up as global variables work but it requires changing source code. So there is no other way I can import some dependency from `node_modules`?

Comment: No there is not, but I agree that would be a cool Chrome plugin.

Comment: This gives me the following error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Answer (score 2):

You could copy-paste the source code of the Lodash library into a [Snippet](https://devtools.chrome.com/snippets).

[image: Lodash Snippet]

Whenever you want to use Lodash on a page, you run the Snippet. After that, the Snippet is available under `window._`.

[image: Lodash in the Console]